# Override salt of Lollipin encryption

Tags: android, encryption, salt, passcode, pin-code

I have implemented my app to use [Lollipin](https://github.com/omadahealth/LolliPin) library to show a Pin Screen when the user is inactive or the app is on background for a long time to protect the app.

I save the generated pin on the server and retrieve it on the login, but when the user is on a new device or clear the data, the salt is lost from the shared preference and creating a new one will use the current milisecs of the system, which won't match the one previously created.

Is there a way to override the AppLockImpl or to customise the salt I want to use?

[image: in]

Comment: Are you targeting android version 6.0 or later ?

Comment: Yes, targeting 6 but I'm still supporting Android 4.